# Conditions for $E[f(X_N)]\to 0$ or $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N f(n)P_N(n)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, limits, expectation

Let $X_N$ be a random variable taking values in $\{1,\dots,N\}$, where $N=1,2,\dots$.

While I already have some options, I am interested in as weak as possible conditions for

$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}E[f(X_N)]=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N f(n)P_N(n)=0,
$$
where $P_N(n)=\Pr(X_N = n)$, and $f:\mathbb{N}\to[0,1/4]$ satisfies $f(n)=O(n^{-\alpha})$ as $n\to\infty$ for some $\alpha>0$.

Hence, I am looking for conditions on probability distributions $\{P_N\}_{N=1}^\infty$.

For a start, while $P_N(n)\to 0$ as $N\to\infty$ for every such $n=1,2,\dots$ that $f(n)\neq 0$ is an obvious necessary condition, I am still unsure whether it may also be sufficient; I couldn't come up with a counterexample to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How much do you know about convergence of probability measures and so on?  One approach to proving your condition is sufficient is by compactifying $\mathbb N$ by adding a point at infinity.  Then your $f$ extends to a continuous bounded function on $\overline{\mathbb N}$ and so forth.

Comment: Ah, that would follow by the Portmanteau lemma, right? It might be a good solution. Is there a way to avoid compactifying $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Of course.  A pure $\epsilon$ and $M$ proof is possible, too: find $M$ so big that $f(n)<\epsilon/2$ whenever $n>M$, and note that $P_N(n<M)\to 0$ as $N\to\infty$, and $P_N(n<M)<\epsilon/2$ whenever $N>N_M$, and so on.  It's a matter of taste, really.

Comment: So $E[f(X_N)] \leq \epsilon_2/2 \sum_{n=1}^{M}f(n)+\epsilon_1/2(1-\epsilon_2/2)$, and the result follows by arbitrariness of $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$, right?

Comment: Yes, I think so.